# Seed file for multiple locale translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, seed

I'm using db/seeds.rb to seed some paragraphs; but I need to seed for multiple languages (I18n).

This is what I have:

```
school = Building.create(
  :body => 'My school'
)
```

This is what I pretend:

```
school = Building.create(
  :body => 'My school'
)
# here I should change locale
school.create(
  :body => 'Mi escuela'
)
```

How should I write my code in order to seed for multiple locale in same seed file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the Globalize Gem: https://github.com/globalize/globalize. Make sure to checkout the instructions for installation and model setup.

Here is an example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :title, :name
end
```

Then in your seed file:

```
I18n.locale = :en
post.title # => 'Globalize rocks!'
post.name  # => 'Globalize'

I18n.locale = :nl
post.title # => ''
post.name  # => 'Globalize'
```